# Prove that $\frac{\partial^{k} f}{\partial x^{i_{1}} \cdots \partial x^{i_{k}}}$ is a tensor.

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Consider a function : $f(x^{1} \dots x^{n}) ($$x^{i}- i$-th coordinate
$) \in C^{\infty}$ and $P$ such point : $\forall 0<l <k$ $\dfrac{\partial ^{l} f}{\partial x^{i_{1}} \dots \partial x^{i_{l}}}$ is zero at point $P$.

Now consider $A_{i_1 \dots i_k} =\dfrac{\partial ^{k} f}{\partial x^{i_{1}} \dots \partial x^{i_{k}}}$ we want to prove that it's a tensor. To prove this we need to check tensor-law:
$A_{i'_1 \dots i'_k} =\dfrac{\partial x^{i_{1}}}{\partial x^{i'_{1}}} \dots \dfrac{\partial x^{i_{k}}}{\partial x^{i'_{k}}} \dfrac{\partial ^{k} f}{\partial x^{i_{1}} \dots \partial x^{i_{k}}}$.

I thought about considering $f = \sum_{n_1 \dots j_n} c(j_1 \dots j_n) x_{i_1}^{j_1} \dots x_{i_n}^{j_n}$ then condition about derivatives gives us some properties about coefficients. 
Maybe there is a better way to prove it?

Comment: Have you tried doing the case $k=2$ to see what's going on?

Comment: @TedShifrin for case $k=2$ we have that all partial derivatives at point $P$ are zero. That's means that function behaves like : $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}$~$g(\bar{x})(\bar{x} -P)$

Comment: I would think more about how the second derivatives transform when you make a change of coordinates. I don't quite understand your statement.

Comment: @TedShifrin you mean: $A_{i'_1, i'_2} =  \dfrac{\partial x^{i_1}}{\partial x^{i'_1}} \dfrac{\partial x^{i_2}}{\partial x^{i'_2}} \dfrac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{i_1}\partial x^{i_2}}$. That's part you are talking about ?

Comment: @TedShifrin the general question is to prove that $A_{i_1 \dots i_k} = \dfrac{\partial^{k} f}{\partial x^{i_1} \dots \partial x^{i_{k}}}$ is a tensor under conditions I've mentioned.

Comment: @TedShifrin and of course $i_{1}$ is a just a index of variable, not a power